# An Elasticsearch filter to determine the absence of a value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that has students and grades for each student. It looks something like this:

```
"name": "bill",
"year": 2015,
"grades": [
   {"subject": "math",    grade: "A"},
   {"subject": "english", grade: "B"}
  ],  ...
```

I'm looking for query filter(s) that can give me:

- a list of students who have studied 'math', and
- a list of students who have *not* studied 'math'.

I'm thinking that an **exists** filter should do it, but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

---

It's a stylised example but the mappings are something like this:

```
  "mappings": {
     "student": {
        "properties": {
           "name": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "grades": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                 "subject": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "grade": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post your index mappings?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas - mappings added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `term filter` should do just fine. For the inverse query, just negate it with a `not filter`:

```
"query": 
{
    "filtered" : {
       "query": {
           "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "term": {
               "grades.subject": "math"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the ones who did not study math:

```
"query": 
{
    "filtered" : {
       "query": {
           "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "not": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                         "grades.subject": "math"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work where grades is a single object, but in my case, grades is an array.

Comment: @pheobas Have you tried it? I'm pretty certain that it works, unless I misunderstood your question. We have pretty much the same case (array of jobs, with industry annotated).

Comment: This worked. My issue was that my mappings had the grades sub document mapped as a 'nested' type and this impacts on how the document is queried.   Need to read up on that now...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a bit your mapping and, depending on the your needs, I'd suggest **aggregations**.

First, your `nested` object needs to be `"include_in_parent": true` so that you can easily do the `not studied 'math'` part:

```
PUT /grades
{
  "mappings": {
    "student": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "grades": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true, 
          "properties": {
            "subject": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "grade": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the full query, using aggregations:

```
GET /grades/student/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "studying_math": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "grades",
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "grades.subject": "math"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_10": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "not_studying_math": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "grades.subject": "math"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_10": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```